# Example to call a costant with "onValueChange" on a Checkbox in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Imagine to have two files:

- **constant.js**, which contains a constant, for example a text to show, that i export
- **app.js**, which contains my checkbox

I would like to import and run (in App.js) the constant contained in constant.js (means showing the text) once i "check" the checkbox using OnValueChange.

Can anyone write a short **working example** to show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the checkbox from React native elements like below
https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/checkbox/

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { CHECKBOX_TEXT } from './constants';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';

export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <View>
      <CheckBox
        center
        title={'Set visible'}
        checked={checked}
        onPress={() => setChecked(!checked)}
      />
   {checked && <Text>{CHECKBOX_TEXT}</Text>}
        </View>
  );
}
```

And have a constants file like this

```
export const CHECKBOX_TEXT='TEXT';
```

You can try this in the below snack
https://snack.expo.io/kityqhINE

Comment: I would like the text to appear when the checbox get "checked" , in your example the text is always there

Comment: Updated the answer, please check

Comment: I checked on the link that you gave me: https://snack.expo.io/TTfyII8vr , still nothing changed

Comment: try the code in the answer, it should work i didnt update the snack yet